# Text after caption causes unintended line breaks or centering

Tags: formatting, captions

I want my figure captions to have the following format:

- Figure number is bold
- First couple of words are the title of the figure and always bold
- Rest of caption is not bold

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cat}
    \caption{A cat} depicted sitting at the table.
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This makes the following:

[image]

I don't like this because the caption shouldn't be centered and also the non-bold text shouldn't be on a new line. It should look like this:

[image]

And the name of the figure in the list of figures (not shown) should be only the bold portion, not the whole thing.

Unacceptable solutions:

- Removing `textfont=bf` and then bolding `A cat` - figure caption will be too long in list of figures.
- Using the short title parameter of `\caption` - I will end up typing every title twice, it's annoying and violates DRY.

Comment: Simply add `\captionsetup{format=plain, justification=justified, font=bf}`.

Comment: @Bernard, I think OP wants only the first 2 words in bold (and they should go to lof).

Comment: @sigur: Yes, I had misread. Your solution is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this? Use the command

```
\mycaption[A cat]{depicted sitting at the table.}
```

In this case you don't need to type it twice; you only need to split it.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1} #2}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures    
\begin{figure}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \mycaption[A cat]{depicted sitting at the table.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```